# A connected component of a graph G is a connected subgraph of G that is not a proper subgraph of another connected subgraph of G?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, graph-connectivity

I'm reading Graph Theory from Kenneth H. Rosen.

> *A connected component of a graph G is a connected subgraph of G that is not a proper subgraph of another connected subgraph of G. That is,
> a connected component of a graph G is a maximal connected
> subgraph of G.*

This confuses me, as I can see from the example that H3 (connected component) *is* a subgraph of H1 (connected component).

What are the connected components of the graph H shown in Figure 3?

[image]

[image]

Comment: $H_3$ is not a subgraph of $H_1$ because they have different vertices. (You may be confused about it being *isomorphic* to a subgraph.) The connected components are $H_1,H_2,H_3$ just like the text says.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A subgraph of $H_1$ is a graph that shares all of its points and edges with $H_1$. For example, the graph consisting of points $abc$ and edges $ab, bc$ is a subgraph of $H_1$.

$H_3$ shares no points or edges with $H_1$, so it is not a subgraph of it. It is isomorphic to a subgraph of $H_1$, but that's not the same as actually being a subgraph of $H_1$.